# Use a variable inside a function in other function

Tags: javascript

I have a scope problem, in this code when I call `mp3.playlistInfo()` `${titlePlayList}` is `undefined`.

How can I use `${titlePlaylist}` inside `playlistInfo: function()`

```
const mp3 = {
    createPlaylist: function() {
        let titlePlaylist = prompt("Choose a name: ")
        console.log(`Your playlist name is: ${titlePlaylist}`)
    },
    playlistInfo: function() {
        console.log(`Already listening ${titlePlaylist}`)
    }
}


mp3.createPlaylist();
mp3.playlistInfo();
```

Comment: As it's defined now, you can't. Define it in the `mp3` object instead as a member variable.

Comment: Put `let titlePlaylist;` as first line of your script. However you're also using `namePlaylist`...?

Comment: What is `titlePlaylist` supposed to be? It's not declared in this code.

Comment: True! I just edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you haven't declared `titlePlaylist` anywhere that's accessible for the other function.
You could solve this by just adding it to the `mp3` object you created.

I would however suggest using a `Class` rather than an `Object`, if you were going to go with this approach.

Simple `Object` based approach

```js
const mp3 = {
    titlePlaylist: null,
    createPlaylist: function() {
        this.titlePlaylist = prompt("Choose a name: ")
        console.log(`Your playlist name is: ${this.titlePlaylist}`)
    },
    playlistInfo: function() {
        console.log(`Already listening ${this.titlePlaylist}`)
    }
}


mp3.createPlaylist();
mp3.playlistInfo();
```

Simple `Class` based approach

```js
class MP3 {
  constructor() {
    this.titlePlaylist = prompt("Choose a name: ");
    this.playlistInfo();
  }
  playlistInfo() {
    console.log(`Already listening ${this.titlePlaylist}`)
  }
}

const mp3 = new MP3();
```

Answer (score 1):

As `mp3` is an object you'll need to set `titlePlaylist` as a property of `mp3`. Then in `createPlaylist` you need to set the returned value from the user to the value of `titlePlaylist`. You can then access `titlePlaylist` in `playlistInfo`, and if you use arrow functions you can skip using `this.titlePlaylist`:

```
const mp3 = {
  titlePlaylist: "",
  createPlaylist: () => {
    titlePlaylist = prompt("Choose a name: ");
    console.log(`Your playlist name is: ${titlePlaylist}`);
  },
  playlistInfo: () => {
    console.log(`Already listening ${titlePlaylist}`);
  },
};

mp3.createPlaylist();
mp3.playlistInfo();
```

You can also achieve this functionality by taking advantage of closures which allow you to get and set variables scoped within the original function body:

```
const mp3Closure = () => {
  let titlePlaylist = "";
  return {
    createPlaylist: () => {
      titlePlaylist = prompt("Choose a name: ");
      console.log(`Your playlist name is: ${titlePlaylist}`);
    },
    playlistInfo: () => {
      console.log(`Already listening ${titlePlaylist}`);
    },
  };
};

const mp3WithClosure = mp3Closure();
mp3WithClosure.createPlaylist();
mp3WithClosure.playlistInfo();
```

Answer (score 0):

OOP variant if needed:

```
class MP3 {
  constructor(titlePlaylist) {
    this.titlePlaylist = titlePlaylist;
  }
  titlePlaylist = null;
  get titlePlaylist() {
    return this.titlePlaylist;
  }
  set titlePlaylist(value) {
    this.titlePlaylist = value;
  }
  createPlaylist = () => {
    this.titlePlaylist = prompt("Choose a name: ");
    console.log(`Your playlist name is: ${this.titlePlaylist}`);
  };
  playlistInfo = () => {
    console.log(`Already listening ${this.titlePlaylist}`);
  };
}
const mp3 = new MP3("");

mp3.createPlaylist();
mp3.playlistInfo();
```